# Synchronized Clipboard?

Tags: laptop, sync, clipboard

Evernote, Dropbox, Xmarks and what not. Many know these but is there a software that can **synchronize clipboard** between devices?  For what you might be asking?  Here is for what:

Sometimes I want URL that I see on my desktop/laptop computer to enter into laptop's/smartphone's browser but unless I save that URL to .TXT file, email URL or save to Evernote there is no other way **to directly do that**.

So is there such software already?

Comment: What operating systems are you running on your desktop, laptop and smartphone?

Comment: This should not matter.

Comment: for your url example, you could use online bookmarks.

Comment: You mean Xmarks?

Answer (score 2):

There is a portable version of a clipboard manager called [Ditto](http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/). You could try installing it on a flash drive and use the flash drive on multiple computers.

Admittedly, this isn't an ideal solution, but it's a start.

Comment: Ditto actually has a feature which does exactly what the OP wants, IIRC.

Comment: IIRC means "if I remember correctly."

Comment: good to know about the meaning :)

Answer (score 1):

Between multiple devices is gonna be real tough unless you get a way to read the clipboard from your Dropbox, but for Windows machines I use www.simidude.com.

Answer (score 1):

For the specific case of sending links to the mobile, since you mentioned an Android device, try Chrome2Phone. It's a [plugin for google chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oadboiipflhobonjjffjbfekfjcgkhco) and an [app for android phone](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.apps.chrometophone) that does just that.

Comment: App does not work with my device.

Answer (score 0):

Between computers is easy.   Between devices is tricky.  You did not post which devices in particular.

AFAIK, neither Windows Phone nor iPhone allow you to monitor the clipboard.  Only the Android. It likely you are asking for the impossible.

Comment: Yes i have Android device. If i could sync clipboard between it and laptop...

Answer (score 0):

If you use Firefox and you have a phone that also supports Firefox, then you can use [Firefox Sync](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/what-firefox-sync), which will sync your bookmarks, open tabs, as well as history, saved passwords, and even add-ons. This way, if you're reading a webpage and suddenly need to go somewhere, you can finish your reading on your phone.

Answer (score 0):

I know, it's a pretty late answer, but I have written an android app and an accompanying server program for windows. (mac and linux support comming soon)

It's called ClipSync, it runs as a service on both windows and android and it will keep the clipboard of your pc and android devices synchronized.

Android app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=be.bdwm.clipsync

Windows server: http://bdwm.be/cs

Comment: Are you planning to implement synchronization through internet, preferrably with SSL capability as well?

Comment: @Boris_yo Lot's of people are asking for this. So yeah, probably. I will make a different app for it though, cause there are also a lot of people who don't like the idea of their sensitive information being sent over the internet, even if it passes trough SSL or any other secure system.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, Synergy will allow clipboard syncing for text. So, if you are using two computers, this is a very convenient solution, especially because it also shares the mouse. A warning, it sometimes has issues (probably due to encoding), for example copying in RStudio on Linux results in pasting Chinese symbols in Word on Linux. But these are not encountered frequently.

Sadly, there is no good synergy client for mobile yet (at least for Android), so this solution is only good for computers. But there, it is awesome.